# Determine value nearest to given coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I'm new to GIS.

I have a raster that specifies the geographical distribution of temperature. I would like to find the temperature that is closest to a particular set of coordinates. How do a find the raster value nearest to [x, y]?

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop.

I have numerous points specified by longitude and latitude in a table that was imported using `Add X-Y Data...` from an Excel spreadsheet. These points plot in the correct places on my map. Nevertheless, the points do not necessarily coincide with data in the raster, so when I do an `Extract Values to Points` I get some -9999 values. Instead, I'd like to know the value of the nearest point where there is data. The output format doesn't really matter, but a column appended to the original table would be ideal. As far as extensions go, I think I have them all, but I can't say for certain.

Comment: Could you clarify what GIS software you are using or have access to?

Comment: There are many possible valid answers, including "just look at it." Could you please help us out by editing this question to stipulate (a) how you want to supply the (x,y) input, (b) whether this is a one-time-only operation or needs to be applied to many coordinates, (c) what format you want the output in, (d) whether you want just to look up a cell value or if you want to interpolate among values in the raster, and (e) what raster-oriented extensions to ArcGIS you have access to.

Comment: Perhaps you are asking the same question posed at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/9398?

Comment: @whuber Thanks! That's pretty much what I was asking. I used the second solution, whereby I converted my raster to points and then did a spatial join between these points and my [x,y] locations.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ArcGIS, you can try the [Extract Values to Points](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z0000002t000000) tool.  It should give you the temperature at each point, assuming they intersect your temperature raster.

Comment: To make this answer more complete; you may first want to create a poiny layer whereas a point is generated in each [x,y] location of interest, than use the tool suggested by @crmackey.

Comment: Pardon guys, I did not get it. "I would like to find the temperature that is closest to a particular set of coordinates". If this guy has a raster where each point specifies a temperature... he could just take value at the point. What this question is about?